# How to get Firefox debug output on Windows

Tags: windows, firefox, crash, logging

Firefox has started reliably crashing on startup. It crashes instantly in normal mode, and after about 4 seconds in safe mode. I'm trying to see any kind of debugging output so I can work out what is causing it but can't find anyway to see any kind of log!

- The `Crash Reports\pending\xxx.dmp` files are binary so not much help.
- If I run it from the console with `-console` it does create a new console window, but nothing is ever written to it, and it closes when Firefox crashes.
- `-attach-console` doesn't seem to work as described.

Any ideas?

Comment: My research suggests entering `about:crashes` in the URL bar, although that doesn't help if the browser is crashing immediately... I'll keep digging.

Comment: Yeah also I tried that in the brief time it survives when launched in safe mode. It appears to just list the crashes in `Crash Reports\pending`. It hasn't survived long enough for me to click on one.

Comment: Aha it seems you can get the filenames from `Crash Reports\pending` and paste them in this URL: https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/bp-...  It says it takes up to 5 minutes to retrieve so I'll see what it says...

Comment: I was about to post the same link!

Answer (score 1):

Not a log, but all of the reported crashes are publicly available (who knew)?

1. Go to `%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Crash Reports\submitted` in Explorer
2. Copy the filename (except `.txt`) of the latest crash, e.g. `bp-21034108-2f5f-47ef-bf66-cf29f2160218`
3. Browse to `https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/<paste filename here>`

In my case it was Websense injecting a DLL (qipcap.dll) that caused Firefox to crash. Fix in [this comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1181091#c59).